# Third party API call not working from microsoft azure

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have used the below piece of code for calling a third-party API from my spring boot application.

```
 @GetMapping("/client-call")
    public String getResponseFromClient(){
        String result = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String uri = "https://blockstream.info/testnet/api/address/tb1qswa0hq3px3arz229y98m67fprw7ujpvxkztgszvt090rkgnq2hysf85hlg/txs";
            result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + result);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

when I deployed this spring boot jar file on a microsoft azure vm, it throws an error of too many requests:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHbp.png)

Comment: check on this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/429-too-many-requests-errors maybe issue with subscription.